# How to set style in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web, fabricjs

Help set the style as the style in the picture. For several days, I try the options, but do not understand how to solve the problem.

[image]

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 150,
    top: 200,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    width: 150,
    height: 120,
    angle: -10,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
    transparentCorners: false
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VINET,

Just add events mouse:over and mouse:out

```
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e){
    if (e.target.type == 'rect'){
    e.target.set({strokeWidth: 5, stroke: 'red'});
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:out', function(e){
    canvas.forEachObject(function(o){
    o.set({strokeWidth: 0});
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06a1b1hp/2/)

**UPDATE:**

If you want to highlight each side separately, you have to create your own stroke for rectangles like here:

```
function createPointsForLines(rectangle){
    let points = [];;
  var coordinates = rectangle.oCoords;
  points.push([coordinates.tl.x, 
        coordinates.tl.y, 
        coordinates.tr.x,
        coordinates.tr.y]);
  points.push([coordinates.tr.x, 
        coordinates.tr.y, 
      coordinates.br.x, 
      coordinates.br.y]);
  points.push([coordinates.br.x, 
        coordinates.br.y, 
      coordinates.bl.x, 
      coordinates.bl.y]);
  points.push([coordinates.bl.x, 
        coordinates.bl.y, 
      coordinates.tl.x, 
      coordinates.tl.y]);
  return points;
}
```

After that draw these strokes as a Lines:

```
for (var i in points){
    var line = new fabric.Line(points[i],{
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    strokeWidth: 10,
    stroke: 'rgba(255,0,0,0)',
    transparentCorners: false
  });

canvas.add(line);
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06a1b1hp/5/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I tried this method, but it is not quite like. It is necessary to make a selection of only one frame.

Comment: So for this I plan to solve this issue. But this solution is not optimal. For this solution, need to associate the scope with objects that require additional calculations. You do not know where these controls are in the library? I think there is somewhere they can be changed and the issue has been resolved.